# Angular4 http repeated calls

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-services, angular-httpclient

If i have 10 form data uploads of 10 service calls.
File sizes are different sizes 2mb,3mb,4mb.

if i make http call of ten calls to upload files to same API.

1) 2mb

2) 3mb

3) 3.5mb

4) 2mb

5) 4mb

6) 2.5mb

7) 3mb

8) 2.8mb

9) 3mb

10) 4mb

which call request will be finished first?
the one with less mb or the one which got called first?
Does angular give priority to the request in order.

Comment: Unless you send those requests sequentially (i.e send the nth one after you got the response for the n-1th one), you can't know. It depends on how fast the server and the network send the response back.